# Swift swiftlint disable regular expression

Tags: swift, regex, swiftlint

I got this swiftlint error from sonarCube:

> Rename this constant to match the regular expression `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$."`.

How can I disable the swiftlint warning from sonarCube?

```
// Rename this constant to match the regular expression ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$.

let zht: [item]
let en: [item]
let zhs: [item]
```

Comment: That trailing dot (meaning “any character”) after the dollar sign (meaning “end of line”) looks like a mistake. How could there be character after the end of the line, for a regex that’s presumably not evaluated in multi-line mode?

Comment: In any case, these variable and type names are just bad. You should fix them.

Comment: Can you share your .swiftlint.yml config file?

Comment: but my api comes with this response.  i only want to disable this regular expression here only without globally disabled. Any disable swiftlint can be used

Comment: You can disable that rule locally in that swift file using `// swiftlint:disable <rule1>`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't think the author uses SwiftLint, they mentioned SonarCube.

Comment: @lazarevzubov ok, I am not familiar with that product and OP mention and has tagged with swiftlint so I leave my comment for now.

Comment: If we assume the dot at the end isn’t part of the regex but a period that ends the sentence then none of the variable names violates the regex so that is also strange. It looks like OP has a lot to clarify here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It [doesn't seem possible in Swift](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/ignore-line-scanning/2214) at the moment, but you don't have to name your variables to match response fields. Do you use `Codable`? If so, it's easy to have any name you wish:

```swift
struct YourModel: Decodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case wantedName = "unwantedNameFromResponse"
  }
  let wantedName: String
}
```

Comment: do i need to rename it?

Comment: The variable? Yes, that was the point. If it's not possible to bypass the linter rule, I suggested renaming the variable with an "invalid" name. You said that the variable name comes from API and I tried to explain that it's not an obstacle.